# To extend the Steiner-Lehmus theorem

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, convex-geometry, plane-geometry, polygons

The Steiner Lehmus theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steiner%E2%80%93Lehmus_theorem) states: Every triangle with two angle bisectors of equal lengths is isosceles.

**Question:** What could one say about symmetries of *convex n-gons* with equal angle bisectors? Obviously, for n=4, all angle bisectors being equal need not make the polygon regular. For general n, can one say (for example): "if all (OR a certain minimum number of OR all alternate) angular bisectors have equal length, the convex n-gon has all angles equal"?

**Note:** I could find no references on this. Moreover, analogous questions can be asked about perpendicular bisectors of sides or lines joining the vertices to the center of mass (analogs of the medians) of a convex n-gon.